# Shopify theme editor settings menu on the wrong side

Tags: shopify

The shopify theme editor settings menu was originally on the left side but now is appearing on the right side of the screen.

[image]

How do I change it so the menu appears on the left side of the screen again?

I know it's probably a simple fix but I haven't been able to find a solution.

**(The greyed out areas have been redacted)**